# How to create VS Load test build in TFS 2015 using command line

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msloadtest

I need to run Visual Studio Load test from TFS using command line. I have following setup - 
1.Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
2.TFS 2015 Update 3
3.Developer Command Prompt for VS2015

I am able to run locally by opening Developer Command Prompt and using commandline /TestContainer:Loadtest.loadtest.
However, i'm not able to do the same in TFS build.

Can you please tell me what I should type in "Tool" and "Argument" fields for command line step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local VS is also using [MSTest.exe command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=vs.120).aspx) to run the Load test.

To run the loadtest in vNext build, you should also use the [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/command-line) task and call `MSTest.exe` command in the build agent.

- Tool: You can specify a fully qualified path of `MSTest.exe` command
- Argument: Specify arguments to pass to the tool. Such as
  `/testcontainer:[ file name ]`

Below is the snapshot from VNext for your reference:

[image]

*Note: You need to use **Test Controller/Test Agents 2013 Update 5** to run load tests on-premises according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents#q--a).*

Comment: Thanks very much. Could you please tell me if it is possible to publish results in TFS? If yes, how?

Comment: @shenQA  As far as I know, the load test result data will save to the loadtest database, not sure if it will  generated a `.trx` file  or not.  If there are, then you could  use the [Publish Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/test/publish-test-results) task in this case.

Comment: It generates .trx file. I have tried using mstest /TestContainer:"C:\WebAndLoadTestProject1\WebAndLoadTestProject1\LoadTest2.loadtest"  /teamproject:"Project Name"   /publishbuild:"$(Build.BuildNumber)"  /publish:url  /flavor:debug /platform:"Any CPU".
But I get an error saying -'Build not found under project xyz'. Any idea?

Comment: Also Publish Test Results task doesn't work for load test result using mstest.

Comment: Hi @shenQA Did you just publish test result failed or the build also failed?  the /publish /publishid  /https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243151(v=vs.120).aspx#/publish is work with the old XAML build， not the new vNext one. If you use Publish Test Results task not work, what's the error message you got?