# TFS On-Premise Load Testing Pipeline

Tags: c#, tfs, performance-testing, mstest, load-testing

Has anyone fit load testing into their on-premise TFS server build/release pipelines? I found other stackoverflow articles on how to trigger the distributed load test using mstest. Currently there isn't an easy way to get the generated statistics in a dashboard. I looked at the cloud load testing options and storing the test results in VSTS seems like too much extra work to bother with. Anyone have suggestions on how to make this less disjointed and actionable? Are there other tools that are worth integrating? Are there simple ways to generate load tests based on swagger/openapi?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what an easy/simple solution do you want to find for the load test. Generally speaking no simple ways, whatever solutions you have to [prepare the environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/lab-management/install-configure-test-agents#q--a).

No any experiences on integrating other tools, all the available ways are listed in the official documents:

Please refer to this guide link for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/?view=vsts

For On-Premise TFS you can reference this thread for details: [How to create VS Load test build in TFS 2015 using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395893/how-to-create-vs-load-test-build-in-tfs-2015-using-command-line)

For Cloud you can reference articles:

- [Run URL-based load tests with VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test?view=vsts)
- [Load test your app in the cloud using Visual Studio and VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/getting-started-with-performance-testing?view=vsts)
- [Load test with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/app-service-web-app-performance-test?view=vsts)
- [View and compare your load test runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/performance-reports?view=vsts)

Comment: @alanmbarr Is the answer helpful? If that helps you could vote it up and if that resolved your issue, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread